# How to align textarea's placeholder to the right bottom?

Tags: css

I can position the placeholder to the right bottom of the textarea at first place, but the placeholder position will be reset after you enter some text and clear the text. anyone know how to prevent the placeholder resetting the position once the text been cleared?

```css
textarea {
    display: block; 
    height: 150px;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 16px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="test">
</textarea>
```

Comment: why don't you use `label` instead of placeholder, because placeholder is just a short hint which displayed in the input field before the user enters a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::placeholder` selector, and then just apply a `text-align:right`. Then to make it appear at the bottom, apply a `transform:translateY(x)` where `x` is the height of the input.

```css
textarea {
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  text-align:right;
  transform: translateY(150px);
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Lorem Ipsum"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `placeholder-text` to align to the ***right*** of the `textarea`, you can simply use:

```
textarea::placeholder {
  text-align: right;
}
```

In order to align the `placeholder-text` at the ***bottom*** of the `textarea`, one approach is to give the `placeholder-text` a `line-height` which corresponds to:

- twice the `height` of the `textarea` minus the `font-size` of the `placeholder-text`

We can do this manually (ie. every time we update the `height` of the `textarea` we also update the `line-height` of the `placeholder-text`) but it's more efficient here to use **CSS Custom Properties** and `calc()`.

If we establish the following custom properties:

```
:root { 
  --textareaHeight : 150px;
  --placeholderFontSize : 14px;
}
```

then we know the `line-height` of the `placeholder-text` is always:

```
calc((var(--textareaHeight) * 2) - var(--placeholderFontSize))
```

This means we can now change the values for `--textareaHeight` and `--placeholderFontSize` arbitrarily and the  `line-height` of the `placeholder-text` will always calculate correctly.

**Working Example:**

```css
:root { 
  --textareaHeight : 150px;
  --placeholderFontSize : 14px;
}

textarea {
    display: block; 
    height: var(--textareaHeight);
    padding: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

textarea::placeholder {
text-align: right;
font-size: --placeholderFontSize;
line-height: calc((var(--textareaHeight) * 2) - var(--placeholderFontSize));
color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: but when I drag the textarea box to have a bigger height, the placeholder can't change hight accordingly

Comment: Yes, you're right. Do you need the textarea box to be `resizable`? If not, you can declare `textarea {resize: none;}` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-group {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 200px;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
      <label>test</label>
      <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
```

This Will always stick to the end of the textarea, length no matter. One more thing you can add jQuery function to hide label when it have some value.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I also want the cursor to start where the placeholder is positioned? How would I do that ? In my case I shifted the "Reply..." placeholder down a bit, but I will be putting something above it, but would like the user's cursor to start at the "R" of "Reply..."
[image]